# Google Agenda PHP Quickstart: syntax error, unexpected

Tags: php, api, agenda

I am using Google official PHP Quickstart file to create a script that will add events to my google agenda.

Following the documentation with the command **php quickstart.php** inside my console.
getting this error:

```
Content-type: text/html

<br />
<b>Parse error</b>:  syntax error, unexpected ')', expecting '(' in <b>/homepages/7/********/htdocs/quickstart.php</b> on line <b>16</b><br />
```

The quickstart.php is the following:

```
<?php
require __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';
/*
if (php_sapi_name() != 'cli') {
    throw new Exception('This application must be run on the command line.');
}
*/
/**
 * Returns an authorized API client.
 * @return Google_Client the authorized client object
 */
function getClient()
{
    $client = new Google_Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Google Calendar API PHP Quickstart');
    $client->setScopes(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);
    $client->setAuthConfig('credentials.json');
    $client->setAccessType('offline');
    $client->setPrompt('select_account consent');

    // Load previously authorized token from a file, if it exists.
    // The file token.json stores the user's access and refresh tokens, and is
    // created automatically when the authorization flow completes for the first
    // time.
    $tokenPath = 'token.json';
    if (file_exists($tokenPath))
    {
        $accessToken = json_decode(file_get_contents($tokenPath) , true);
        $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);
    }

    // If there is no previous token or it's expired.
    if ($client->isAccessTokenExpired())
    {
        // Refresh the token if possible, else fetch a new one.
        if ($client->getRefreshToken())
        {
            $client->fetchAccessTokenWithRefreshToken($client->getRefreshToken());
        }
        else
        {
            // Request authorization from the user.
            $authUrl = $client->createAuthUrl();
            printf("Open the following link in your browser:\n%s\n", $authUrl);
            print 'Enter verification code: ';
            $authCode = trim(fgets(STDIN));

            // Exchange authorization code for an access token.
            $accessToken = $client->fetchAccessTokenWithAuthCode($authCode);
            $client->setAccessToken($accessToken);

            // Check to see if there was an error.
            if (array_key_exists('error', $accessToken))
            {
                throw new Exception(join(', ', $accessToken));
            }
        }
        // Save the token to a file.
        if (!file_exists(dirname($tokenPath)))
        {
            mkdir(dirname($tokenPath) , 0700, true);
        }
        file_put_contents($tokenPath, json_encode($client->getAccessToken()));
    }
    return $client;
}

// Get the API client and construct the service object.
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Calendar($client);
```

Line 16 is:

$client->setScopes(Google_Service_Calendar::CALENDAR);

Comment: The syntax looks fine to me, so I'm going to guess it may be invisible characters. Try deleting that line and the line above it, and retype them.

Comment: still the same..

Comment: why does your output examples shows up `Content-type: text/html`? it should not be there when you run from console. Also it bugs me that you've commented out `php_sapi_name()` check, return it back.
Are you sure you run example from console instead of opening it in browser?